# Array is empty, even though it is set in attached

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I have the following code:

```
Grid get _gridA => $['myGridA'];
Grid get _gridB => $['myGridB'];
Grid get _gridC => $['myGridC'];
List<Grid> _grids = [];
Grid _selectedGrid = null;

attached(){
  // Sets array and sets the defaul selected Grid.
  _grids = [_gridA, _gridB, _gridC];
  _selectedGrid = _grids[0];
}

onTabChange(index, _){
 //crashes here, because at this point, _grids is still [] and not [a,b,c]
  _selectedGrid = _grids[index];
}
```

Is there a way to resolve this?  `set` doesnt do anything either.
When trying to instantiate it at the top where i defined it as `[]`, I would get the error that I cant have non-static items in my array.

Comment: Does this mean `onTabChange()` is called before `attached()`?

Comment: It shouldnt.   They are both on the page.  The onTabChange calls when i toggle between child components on the page

Comment: I would throw a print statement into `attached` and `onTabChange`. It could be that `attached` is never getting called (if this is a `Behavior` for instance it would need to be a static method), or `onTabChange` is just getting called first.

Comment: Yep that was it.  It looks like the attached function runs after onTabChange.  Most likely, the Child component will run and then call onTabChanged as a part of its initializer to select the first one.  After all the subcomponents are done doing their things, the parent attached would get called.

So that being said, What would be a solid idea to resolve this?  Maybe set it on created instead of attached i guess?